# RewriteCond for ipv6 subnet under .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ipv6

i'm having a question related to ipv6 address that reach a website.
The apache logs, shows clients x-forward ips under ipv4 and ipv6

This website is protected under .htaccess via a ipv4 whitelist for each allowed subnet.

Example :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR}  !^123\.45\.67
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR}  !^123\.45\.68
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR}  !^123\.45\.69
```

How can i do the same for a ipv6 prefix , since the following does not seems to work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR}  !^\[1234:123:123::/48\]
```

If i specify the ipv6 client ip in the rewritecond it works. But only for a period of time until his ipv6 address gets renewed.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try:

```
RewriteCond expr "! %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} -ipmatch '1234:123:123::/48'"
```

It implies Apache >= 2.4, native (meaning without the use of an *expr*ession) `RewriteCond` does not handle IP range/CIDR notation.

Comment: Yes, the RewriteConds in the question are just performing a regexp check on the string. Comparing an address to a subnet requires different logic.